# Using quoted variable names when creating functions containing ellipses (i.e. '...') in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to learn how to use the ellipses (`...`) when I program using dplyr. I cannot work out how to pass a character into the ellipses. Here is a toy problem to illustrate

```
set.seed(10)
data.frame(var1 = factor(sample(x = letters[1:3],
                                size = 10,
                                replace = T))) -> df
```

Now say I want to get simple frequencies of each level of the factor. I make a simple function to do that

```
levelFunct <- function(.data, ...) {
  .data %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
      summarise(count = n()) %>%
        mutate(tot = sum(count),
               perc = round(count/tot*100,2))
}
```

Now when I run the function this way, just passing the name of the variable into the ellipse argument without quotation marks

```
levelFunct(df, var1)
```

I get the following output

```
  var1  count   tot  perc
  <fct> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 a         1    10    10
2 b         2    10    20
3 c         7    10    70
```

So far so good. But if I pass the function into the ellipse argument with quotation marks

levelFunct(df, "var1")

I get the following output

```
  `"var1"` count   tot  perc
  <chr>    <int> <int> <dbl>
1 var1        10    10   100
```

So **how do I replicate the result from the first run using a quoted variable name?**

I tried enclosing the ellipse in the `group_by` function in double brackets (`[[...]]`) but just got an error.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're after - are you wanting a function that can take both string input and symbols?  And do you want to stick with using the ellipse or are you happy for an alternative?

Comment: The problem is the mixing of the strings and symbols. You can get around this, although it will be a mess if the variable is something stored in another variable

Comment: Hi @Ritchie Sacramento. It doesn't need to be able to use *either* strings or symbols, just one that can use strings. And yes I would like to be able to use the ellipses. I'm just wondering if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

In those situations, you must use the .data pronoun:

```
levelFunct(df, .data[["var1"]])
```

**NOTE:**

You can pass more parameters aside that, literal string or var name.

`levelFunct(df, .data[["var1"]], var2, .....)`

in general, methods described here are valid:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 2):

Using the `rlang` library, you can change the quosures as below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

levelFunct <- function(.data, ...) {
  qs <- map(enquos(...), 
      ~if(!quo_is_symbol(.x))quo_set_expr(.x, sym(quo_get_expr(.x)))
      else .x)
  .data %>%
    group_by(!!!qs) %>%
      summarise(count = n()) %>%
        mutate(tot = sum(count),
               perc = round(count/tot*100,2))
}

levelFunct(df, "var1")
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  var1  count   tot  perc
  <fct> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 a         1    10    10
2 b         2    10    20
3 c         7    10    70
> levelFunct(df, var1)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  var1  count   tot  perc
  <fct> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 a         1    10    10
2 b         2    10    20
3 c         7    10    70
```

Comment: Your knowledge of the quosure verbs is enviable @onyambu, and well beyond my understanding. I understand everything except the money line: `!quo_is_symbol(.x))quo_set_expr(.x, sym(quo_get_expr(.x))`. I don't suppose you can talk me through it can you?

Comment: @llewmills that is an if else line. `If the quosure expression is not symbolic` then convert the string to symbolic and then set the quosure expression with the converted expression. Note that using base R would be straight forward although base R does not directly support injections and splicing.